# AJAX causing Chrome to say the site is unresponsive

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

For one of the pages on my company's site, we have to verify a user's phone number. In order to do this, I use AJAX to call a Voice XML app that calls the phone number provided by the user, and waits for them to enter a randomly generated PIN. Once we get a response from the voice app (either correct PIN, incorrect PIN, or no answer) it forwards that response back and finishes the AJAX call.

This whole process can take up to a minute, and works perfectly fine except in Chrome. When using Chrome, I get the popup that says "This page appears to be unresponsive..." If I ignore the popup and just let the call finish, everything works fine as expected. The call finishes, AJAX completes, and the user gets redirected to a page saying whether or not verification was successful.

I am looking for a way to avoid Chrome marking the page as non-responsive. Management is worried it will look unprofessional, and if customer's opt to kill the unresponsive page submission is never completed.

The AJAX call happens on a form submit inside an iFrame, if that has any impact.

```
function callNow()
{

// Disable the button so they don't keep clicking while the call is going on.
$("#call_now").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#call_now").unbind("click");

$(".state_a").hide();
$(".state_b").show();

// Wait 50 msec so that the 'processing' field can show.
setTimeout(function() {

    // Make an ajax call to initiate the call
    $.ajax({ url: "/ajax-quicksign-verify-now.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: {action: 1,
            number: $("#number").val(),
            pin: $("#pin").text()},
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == 1) {
                $("#verified").val("true");
            } else {
                $("#verified").val("false");
            }
            $("#quicksign_register").submit();
            return;
        }
    });

}, 50);
```

Comment: The problem is here `async: false,`, that causes the page to become unresponsive, remove it.

Comment: Do you have a valid reason for making the AJAX call synchronous?

Comment: We had a similar problem with another VXML AJAX call elsewhere on the site, and changing from async: true; to async: false; fixed the issue there, so I kept it that way here. FWIW, changing to async: true here appears to have resolved the issue

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here `async: false`, that causes the page to become unresponsive, remove it.

Or change it to `async: true`.